# 1996 Mazda Soho 1.3 - Idle throttle control valve acting up

Tags: electrical, mazda, idle, throttle

I bought a Mazda Soho 121 roughly a year ago, that had an idling problem.

After tracing the issue down to the idle control valve (idle would jump from 500rpm to 3500 rpm every second or two), I managed to replace with a brand new one from the local Ford dealership (SAMCOR model, so Ford and Mazda shared a factory, even the branding all over my engine is stamped with Ford). This fixed the issue.

Now however after just three weeks, it has started all over again.
Any ideas on what I can check?

I am not the most mechanically minded, but I am starting to reach a small level of competence, so seeking advice from those more in the know.

Comment: what happens if you disconnect the idle air valve does it idle at base idle ~500ish rpm?